# Retornar dia da Semana conforme data

Tags: data

Boa tarde.
Preciso fazer no vba a seguinte função.
Com a função Date, consigo pegar o dia atual, e com esse dia, quero sempre pegar a data da quinta feira, daquela semana.

Exemplo: o Date retornou dia 01/05/2019, preciso que ele veja qual a quinta feira daquela semana e retorne a data da semana, no caso 02/05/2019.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Da uma olhada neste post, que acho que vai te ajudar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973143/mm-dd-yyyy-to-day-of-week-analyzing-consecutive-working-days

Comment: Rafael, qual a linguagem de programação?

Comment: estou usando o VBA no Excel